# How to use types with typescript on highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I've read [the docs regarding typescript on Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations) but I still don't have it very clear how to use types in highcharts.js functions.

For example, I have a `formatter` function on my `tooltip` options and it admits a parameter `this`. How do I type it?

Right now I'm using `any` but that's just to bypass the typescript errors. I don't want to manually type it in case Highcharts updates its content in future versions, so I assume there's a proper way of doing it?

```js
const options = {
    tooltip: {
      outside: true,
      formatter: function (this: any): string {  // <---- need to replace `any` here
      }
    }
}
```

What type should I use there?
And how do I find out exactly which of them should I use?

I've tried using `Highcharts.TooltipFormatterCallbackFunction` as that's what seems to be indicated in [the callback docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter).

```js
formatter: function (this: Highcharts.TooltipFormatterCallbackFunction): string {
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize the property `y` inside the `this` object. `this.y`.
Perhaps that's the return type? Where do I look for the one for `this`?

[image]

Same problem with `plotOptions.column.point.events.mouseOver`:

```js
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function (this: any) { //<-- here
                    this.graphic.attr({
                       fill: this.y < 0 ? "red" : "blue",
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chech the proper types in the Highcharts API.

For `this` in a tooltip formatter function use: `Highcharts.TooltipFormatterContextObject`

For `this` in a mouse over callback function use: `Highcharts.Point`

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.TooltipFormatterCallbackFunction

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.PointMouseOverCallbackFunction